# Typescript UMD import problems into ESNext module

Tags: javascript, typescript

Historically most of my browser projects have been built with UMD modules. I'm trying to switch over to ESNext.

I'm just trying to import a UMD module, like so:

```
import {Chart, ChartDataSets, ChartConfiguration} from './com/chart';
```

Typescript is fine with this, but the browser throws the error: `Loading module from [...]/com/chart was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).`

Fine. So I tried it with the js file extension:

```
import {Chart, ChartDataSets, ChartConfiguration} from './com/chart.js';
```

I get: `Import not found: Chart`.

Tried to import the whole thing:

```
import * as Chart from './com/chart.js';
```

Chart is not a constructor. Chart.Chart is undefined.

Tried it as a reference type, including a script tag in the HTML:

```
///<reference types='./com/chart'/>
```

This isn't ideal, but it worked. However, Typescript doesn't like it:

`'Chart' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.ts(2686)`

Yeah, I tried adding an import. I'm not clear on something. Why is the module being treated differently when I import it with the .js file extension?

Comment: what webserver are you using to serve the files ? The mime shouldn't be text/html.

Comment: It's Apache. What I'm actually seeing is when I put the import statement into typescript as `./com/chart' without the `.js`, the browser tries to literally import a file called `chart` and gets a 404. Which makes sense since it's just emitting as an ES import statement in javascript. The issue I guess is that when imported with the .js extension, it's not being interpreted as a module.